# Forward Domain with masking to a Wordpress blog

Tags: .htaccess, dns, masking, forwarding

Here's what I'm trying to do.

I have a URL/sub-domain - blog.mydomain.com (which used to deliver a wordpress blog on my own server. I want to eventually shut it down.)

I have a new domain - brandNewDomain.com - (which is the new host for my blog - I have transferred all my data over to this new domain, which is hosted by goDaddy.com)

I want to users who enter blog.mydomain.com - to get forwarded to the new domain - brandNewDomain.com - but I also want to mask the name, brandNewDomain.com

My research so far suggests that after I alter the A record for blog.mydomain.com to point to the IP address of brandNewDomain.com - some htaccess configuration on the server hosting brandNewDomain.com will be required. But I'm not sure what I would need to do.

Any ideas? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to resolve this. The domain - blog.mydomain.com was first set up in our godaddy hosting account. Then, in wordpress (via phpmyadmin) I changed the Home and siteurl settings in the mysql options table FROM, brandNewDomain.com TO blog.mydomain.com. After that I pointed blog.mydomain.com at the IP for brandNewDomain.com.